# java.sql.SQLException: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 and 1st column of my data base is auto incrimented

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, dao

i am trying to insert values in data base so that if user choice marks base then marks are saved and if user choice grade base marks feild is left empty and grades should be stored my my primary key is gid which is auto incriment and sid is forign key here i am unable to get and resolve this error if someone could help me it would be pleasure.

```
private void hide1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
    regstration r=new regstration();
        Daoregistration dao=new Daoregistration();
        if(mark1.getText().length()<0)
        {
            r.marks=Integer.parseInt(mark1.getText());
        }
         r.ch=Integer.parseInt(jComboBox2. getSelectedItem().toString());
         r.semister=jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString();
         r.subject1=subj1.getText();
          if(jRadioButton2.isSelected()){
         r.grade1=(String)jComboBox3.getSelectedItem();
        
          }
          int a =dao.gpa(r);
     System.out.print(a);
          try{
     String qry="select * from formula where grades=? or percentage=?";
     
    PreparedStatement pst=dao.con.prepareStatement(qry);
    pst.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(mark1.getText()));
    pst.setString(2,(String)jComboBox3.getSelectedItem());
    ResultSet rs=pst.executeQuery();
    if(rs.next())
    {
    r.gpoint=rs.getFloat("grade points");
          }
    
    
    }
          catch(Exception ex){
        }
            subj1.setVisible(false);
            mark1.setVisible(false);
           
           jComboBox2.setVisible(false);
              jComboBox3.setVisible(false);
        }                                     
    
        private void hide2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
            subj2.setVisible(false);
            mark2.setVisible(false);
           
           jComboBox4.setVisible(false);
              jComboBox10.setVisible(false);
        }                                     
    
        private void jComboBox5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
            // TODO add your handling code here:
        }                                          
    
        private void hide3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
            subj3.setVisible(false);
            mark3.setVisible(false);
           
           jComboBox5.setVisible(false);
              jComboBox11.setVisible(false);
        }                                     
    
        private void hide4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
            subj4.setVisible(false);
            mark4.setVisible(false);
           
           jComboBox6.setVisible(false);
              jComboBox12.setVisible(false);
        }
```

and my gpa module code is

```
int gpa(regstration r)
    {
        int res=0;
         try{
              connection();
             String qry="insert into gpa values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
             PreparedStatement pst=con.prepareStatement(qry);
             pst.setInt(1, r.sid);
             pst.setString(2,r.semister);
              pst.setString(3,r.subject1);
              
              pst.setInt(4,r.marks);
              
             pst.setString(5,r.grade1);
              pst.setInt(6,r.ch);
               pst.setFloat(7,r.gpoint);
             
            
             
             res=pst.executeUpdate();
             
    }
         catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
          return res;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Specify the columns in the insert statement

```
String qry="insert into gpa (col1, ... , col7) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
```

The count of columns must match the count of the question marks.